# Access the value of a property with dashes in property name for environment variable assignment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, deployment, configuration

I have a values.yaml where I'm storing a value in a property and a deployment.yaml where I'm trying to assign that value to an environment variable. The problem is the property name includes dashes and the following error message is thrown.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'security.enable-mock-service' to boolean:

    Property: security.enable-mock-service
    Value:
    Origin: System Environment Property "SECURITY_ENABLEMOCKSERVICE"
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to boolean (caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A null value cannot be assigned to a primitive type)
```

The 'null value' is because I'm trying to reference the name as {{ Values.security.enablemockservice | quote }} without the dashes using relaxed binding, but the actual property name is Values.security.enable-mock-service. If I attempt to reference the name in deployment.yaml as {{ Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}, I get the following error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: parse error at (project/templates/deployment.yaml:105): bad character U+002D '-'
```

Evidently relaxed binding can't be used in this way or I don't understand how to use it. Is there any other way to reference this property?

Here is the code in my two files:

**values.yaml**

```
  security:
     enable-mock-service: "false"
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
- name: SECURITY_ENABLEMOCKSERVICE
  value: {{ .Values.security.enablemockservice | quote }}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

We wish to write something like:

```
   value: {{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}
```

But, **Dash "-" is a reserved character in YAML** so, we cannot directly use it.

### The Fix

According to YAML spec, to escape dash "-", there are multiple options:

```
value: '{{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}'
value: "{{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}"
value: 
    {{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}
value: >-
    {{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}
value: |-
    {{ .Values.security.enable-mock-service | quote }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, but doesn't seem to work. Maybe the {{ }} notation is causing problems

Comment: Finally fixed: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2192